# Output JIRA filter to website via REST query?

Tags: php, html, rest, jira

I'm creating a kind of portal for my team as part of our company's annual Hackathon and wanted to include results for a specific JIRA filter on the front page of said portal. Idea is so that when you log in, you bring up the portal and it'll show you a list of the latest issues say or upcoming changes or RFCs for your attention.

Could I do this via REST where a script automatically grabs the content and then updates a HTML or PHP file with it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, depends on your JQL I believe you can do it via REST API. Atlassian documentation contains couple of good examples of the REST API and JQL. You can take a look at it [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-query-issues).